# Does SaveMode impact on DropAll?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDb, c# driver: Does SaveMode option impact on "all data dropping" operation in MongoDb? If so, is it possible to deactivate SafeMode (SafeMode.False) for single DropAll operation? I know it is possible for update operation The idea is to drop all items from collection before adding new items

Answer (score 0):

when you are using collection.drop [collection c# code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Driver/Core/MongoCollection.cs#L255)
it is using the db command. This is should use the write concern of your connection. There shouldn't bee any bug differences between SAFE and UNSAFE.

So YES there is an impact but NO it is not deleting every single documente (unless you are using remove()) so it is a fast command. And If you want to make sure that this command it is applied to memory in the db, i would not use UNSAFE.